# Can this simple Bank example be considered as a valid Abstract Factory?

Tags: design-patterns, interfaces, uml, abstract-class, abstract-factory

For teaching purposes, I'm trying to replicate in a more faithful way from this conceptual UML (from wikipedia):

[image: conceptual abstract factory]

In a "so-so" real world example, in my case, families of **Loans** and **Insurances**:

[image: my abstract factory]

So, can it be considered a valid GOF Abstract Factory?

Have I followed all the original principles? Or does it needs any kind of fix?

Comment: Did you tried to implement it in the code? Did implementation fit your requirements?

Comment: I am trying using PHP, at this moments yes but using abstract classes instead interfaces

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram corresponds to an abstract factory according to the GoF.

In the original GoF, the diagrams did not use UML but a slightly modified version of Rumbaugh's OMT, which did not make difference between class inheritance and interface realization.

From an UML point of view, the dotted arrow already represents the [interface realization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/realization.html).  There is no need to add an [`«extend»`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html) keyword which in UML is meant for use-cases and means something different. Morevoer in java [`extends`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_extends.asp) is used for class inheritance, which would add to the confusion in your diagram.  Simply let this keyword out.

It's not necessary, but I'd show the keyword `«use»` for the dependency between the client and the abstract factory,  and [`«create»`](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html#create) for the products, because it helps the diagram to better understand the purpose.  But this is a stylistic comment that you can ignore.